# How to call WCF service in xamarin Android application

Tags: c#, android, web-services

I have seen few solutions for the same question but it was helpless for me. As I am using WCF web service first time in my application, I used following code to consume it but I am not getting result or it pushes me in exception case.

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
            button.Click += delegate {
                // button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);

                try
                {
                    localhost.Service1 myServ = new localhost.Service1();
                    myServ.Url = "http://192.168.1.103:49500/Service1.svc";
                    // Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
                    button.Text = myServ.getMyWS();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    button.Text = ex.Message;
                }
            };
}
```

Method in WCF service is :

```
 public string getMyWS()
        {
            return string.Format("Hello Dipak");
        }
```

This is my sample web service to change the text of button by result of web service and purpose is to learn web service call from server.
What changes to be made to make it work?

Comment: your codes also not working for me